# Can not set multi line string to environment variable

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-rm-template

How can I set multi line string to environment variable on VSTS powershell task. Following code only save the first line of the string.

`[string]$xmlstring = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path 
   "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/apiPolicy.xml"  -Raw | Out-String;
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=policystring;]"+$xmlstring)`

Comment: I have ended up encoding the string into Base64 and store it on environment variable and use "base64ToString(parameters('PolicyContent'))]" on ARM template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple lines variable in build or release is not supported, so it can’t be set the multiple variable during the build/release too.

Related user voice: [Multiple lines variable in Build and Release](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19566427-multiple-lines-variable-in-build-and-release).

To do it with the base64 string is the good way.