# Output variable in Azure Devops looses everything after first line break

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I get contents of a file in inline PS script:

```
$text = Get-Content $(FilePath) -Raw 
#everything gets printed
Write-Host $text
#I save it in the variable
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]$text"
```

Then in downstream(next) PS task I refer to that variable:

```
Write-Host $(testvar)
```

and only the first line of the file content is printed. Why is that, how do I keep all content?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [multi-line string variables aren't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649016/can-not-set-multi-line-string-to-environment-variable).

As suggested in that answer, you could base64-encode the whole string and use that as the variable value:

```
$text = Get-Content $(FilePath) -Raw 

# encode string as UTF8 byte array, encode byte array as base64 string
$b64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text))

# set variable value to base64
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]$b64"
```

And then in the downstream task:

```
$text = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($testVar))

Write-Host $text
```